# ANDROID STUDIO The System cannot find the path specified

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have updated my Android Studio to the Artic Fox Version. After that neither the projects with old Gradle versions running nor the new projects with latest Gradle versions running. Only the following errors appears:
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https: //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip'

After this error I manually downloaded the Gradle 7.0.2, extracted it and Set it as Gradle path in Android Studio > File>Settings>Gradle and choose the option "Use Gradle from Specified Location".
But all in vain. Only I can see the following message, when I try to Sync project with Gradle.

"The system cannot find the path specified."
I have been searching this problem for two days on internet, but nothing worked out for me.

Current Path where I have downloaded and extracted the Gradle Distribution is follows
F:/Android Gradle/gradle-7.0.2

What mistake I am making?

Comment: Try pointing it towards the bin folder of your Gradle distribution.

Comment: Noticed that the error, is the `distributionUrl` in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` wrongly written as `https: //` not `https://` with an extra whitespace?

Comment: @GenoChen I noticed the same. But I though it could be there only on stackoverflow. The gradle.properties is auto-generated though, so I don't think that would be the case here.

Comment: Geno Chen. Thanks for Reply. But the other problem is that My .gradle folder only have one file that is gradle.properties. It has no other other folder or file inside it. My .gradle folder is at following location: C:\Users\Saboor-PC\.gradle

Comment: @JustInCoding I have tried to point to bin folder of my Gradle distribution but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: I am also thinking about Gradle Home Environment variable. I tried to change the value of that variable to the path where  I downloaded the  Gradle distribution. But that did not solve the problem either. What you guys think? is there any connection with the Gradle Home Environment Variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping. I have tried all the methods but my problem did not solve.
I just downgraded the version of Android studio and the problem is solved now.